# Kendo UI Grid using OData returns "The query parameter '$count' is not supported."

Tags: c#, kendo-ui, telerik, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I am trying to implement OData on a Kendo Grid to evaluate the performance (I've worked with using Entity Framework, inline sql, etc). In my api project, I'm using OData v4 as that seems to be what Telerik works with. In my api controller I have:

```
[HttpGet]
[Queryable(AllowedQueryOptions = AllowedQueryOptions.All)]
[EnableCors(origins: "http://localhost:50264", headers: "*", methods: "*")]
public IQueryable<vNPISearch> Search(string id)
{
    return !String.IsNullOrEmpty(id) ? oandpService.GetPecosQueryable(id) : Enumerable.Empty<vNPISearch>().AsQueryable();
}
```

And my grid looks like:

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<vNPISearch>()
        .Name("npi-grid")
        .Columns(columns =>
        {
            columns.Template(x => { }).ClientTemplate("#=GetPecosStatus(PecosNPI) #").Width(50);
            columns.Bound(x => x.ProviderFirstName).Title("First Name");
            columns.Bound(x => x.ProviderLastName).Title("Last Name");
            columns.Bound(x => x.ProviderBusinessLocationAddressCity).Title("City");
            columns.Bound(x => x.ProviderBusinessLocationAddressState).Title("State");
            columns.Bound(x => x.NPI).Title("NPI");
        })
        .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
    .Custom()
    .Schema(sch =>
    {
        sch.Model(m =>
        {
            m.Id("NPI");
            m.Field(f => f.NPI).Editable(false);
            m.Field(f => f.ProviderFirstName).Editable(false);
            m.Field(f => f.ProviderLastName).Editable(false);
            m.Field(f => f.ProviderBusinessLocationAddressCity).Editable(false);
            m.Field(f => f.ProviderBusinessLocationAddressState).Editable(false);
        });
    })
    .Type("odata")
    .Transport(transport =>
    {
        transport.Read(read =>
        {
            read.Url("http://localhost:58242/api/PecosSearch/Search?id=" + Model.SearchTerm);
            read.DataType("json");
        });
    })
    .PageSize(20)
    .ServerPaging(true)
    .ServerSorting(true)
    .ServerFiltering(true)
)
        .Scrollable(scr => scr.Height("auto"))
        .Sortable()
        .Pageable(pageable => pageable
            .Refresh(true)
            .PageSizes(true)
            .ButtonCount(5))
)
```

When I go to the search page, which has a search textbox and the grid. When I run a query against it, I get "The query parameter '$count' is not supported."

The API works if I remove $count in Postman.

Any idea what's going on?

Thanks,

AJ

Comment: First, try changing .Type("odata") to .Type("odata-v4"). https://github.com/telerik/ui-for-aspnet-mvc-examples/blob/master/grid/odata-v4-web-api-binding-wrappers/KendoUIMVC5/Views/Home/Index.cshtml

Comment: Thanks, but I've tried that :(

Comment: I'd suspect the api side. What [DataServiceVersion](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/gg312156.aspx#DetermineDataServiceVersion) is it returning?

Comment: I'm actually not sure. I installed this addon (https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/http-headers/mhbpoeinkhpajikalhfpjjafpfgjnmgk) but it doesn't show DataServiceVersion in the headers...

Comment: Is your controller inheriting from ODataController or ApiController?

Comment: I was using ApiController, changed it to ODataController and now when I try to search I get "406 (Not Acceptable)". Thank you for your help!

Comment: Could be you have mixed OData versions. Search for System.Web.Http.OData which is old and use System.Web.OData. Could also be the routes - make sure odata routes come ahead of api routes.

Comment: Alright, so I removed all previously installed Odata packages and installed System.Web.OData. Now I get "No non-OData HTTP route registered." In our "big" api, we're using the latest version of OData and it's so simple. This OData v4 is a PITA!

Comment: Have you setup an odata route (MapODataServiceRoute)? Then call it like  http://localhost:58242/odata/PecosSearch/....

Comment: I'm about to throw this ODatav4 out the door, I really wish that the Kendo UI Grid supported v5, as it's not nearly as difficult to implement. In any case, you can check out my code here: https://gist.github.com/ajtatum/caa51247760f06be8f4d5a2f8083edc5

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to return this value from the server using the `ToDataSourceResult` extension method.

```
    using using Kendo.Mvc.Extensions;

    public ActionResult Search(string id, [DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request){
        return !String.IsNullOrEmpty(id) ? oandpService.GetPecosQueryable(id).ToDataSourceResult(request) : Enumerable.Empty<vNPISearch>().AsQueryable().ToDataSourceResult(request);
    }
```

Edit: Changing the collection to ActionResult will allow the data to pass.

Comment: Thanks for the response. When I do that, I get the error "Cannot implicity convert type DataSourceResult to IQueryable<vNPISearch>.

Comment: Does it work if you change the result type to ActionResult.

Comment: That just gives the error "Cannot implicitly convert DataSourceResult to ActionResult.